# Second derivative filter

Tags: matlab

The filter f’ = [0 -1/2 0 1/2 0] gives an estimate of the first derivative of the image in the x direction. What is the corresponding second derivative filter f"?

Can someone give me a clue and guide me as to how I would go about this problem?

Comment: On the DSP site http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10605/kernels-to-compute-second-order-derivative-of-digital-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a 1-D signal, use `[.5, -1, .5]`. In the case of an image what you are looking for is probably the "Laplacean" filter, but the actual second derivative is more complicated than that. It's not a single filter, and it's definitely not just a 1-D array.

The "second derivative" could be that filter applied to the x or the y direction. Their sum is the Laplacian. But there is also dxy/dxdy, which is the convolution by something like:

```
[[-1, 0, 1],
 [ 0, 0, 0],
 [ 1, 0,-1]]
```

You should also use something like

```
[[-1, 0, 1],
 [-2, 0, 2],
 [-1, 0, 1]]]
```

when calculating the directional derivatives.

If you really want to understand how all of that works, look for the excellent book "Digital Filters" by Richard Hamming! Too many people use these oversimple filters. Try to learn about windowing and Lanczos smoothing. Also there is little reason for anyone not to be using stuff like [Shigeru Ando's consistent gradient operators](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=841757).

Comment: what would the second derivative look like for just the x direction? @dividebyzero

Comment: You just replicate the filter on three lines, and apply some weight. Like [[1,-2,1], [2,-4,2], [1,-2,1]].